# How to Install Windows XP on old IDE/SATA hard disk (connected in USB) for on old PC?

Tags: ide, installation, windows-xp, hard-drive, sata

I have an old PC (Intel Pentium 4/2 GB RAM) with Windows XP crash : blue screen at startup. So I want to reinstall XP: problem, I haven't CD/DVD player in the tower and the bios does not boot USB...

So **I got the Hard Drive 3.5 "IDE / SATA and I connected via USB to a laptop thanks to an IDE to USB converter**.

==> **Mission: Install Windows XP SP3 (I have the ISO) on this IDE hard drive connected via USB for it boots when I set up it in my old Intel P4 PC**.

[image]

==> How there is there a tutorial, or a video ? It's hard to find it, I find that tutorials for install USB only...

Thank you for your help.

Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need software

- smartdrive, download it [here](http://downloads.ziddu.com/download/10504455/SMARTDRV.zip.html/eng)
- DOS 7.10, or download [DOS 7.10](http://www.ziddu.com/downloadlink/10504378/dos71_1.zip)

Now format your harddrive with `fat32` system, install `DOS 7.1` onto it and copy `smartdrv.exe` to your hard drive.

Afterwards, copy folder `I386` from your XP installation CD. Unplug your hard drive and put your hard drive back to your old PC. Turn on your old pc and it will automatically startup to `DOS 7.1`.

In prompt C:> write `smartdrv` and then hit Enter.

Afterwards, also in prompt C:>, write `I386\winnt.exe`

Wait for installation process finished.

Comment: Links are all dead. The version of SmartDrive should be indicated too...